# Can you run Zookeeper cluster without using statefulsets in openshift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, apache-zookeeper

I have a single instance of zookeeper running without issues, however when I add two more nodes it crashes with leader election or we got a connection request from the server with own id.

Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should use statefulset.
Would you like community help you - please provide logs and errors of crushes.

Comment: I made it work by using the bitnami/zookeeper to create a cluster using deployment config . I had to use 3 deployment configs and each dc having a service created and then myid was injected on each of this at the data dir.. However i felt that as a bad practice.. Statefulsets seems to be a better alternative although it does not work with that zookeeper version. I have to use the gcr kubernetes-zookeeper to get it working. Thanks